# Markov inequality when a given event holds?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, inequality

Given a non-negative random variable, for $a>0$, by Markov inequality , we know that
$$P(Z\ge a)\le \frac{EZ}{a}.$$

If $\mathcal{A}$ is some event, is it true that
$$P(Z\ge a \text{ and }\mathcal{A} \text{ holds})\le \frac{E(Z\mathbf{1}_{\{\mathcal{A} \text{ holds} \}})}{a}?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  This is just Markov's inequality applied to the random variable $Z 1_{\mathcal{A}}$.  Simply note that $Z 1_{\mathcal{A}} \ge a$ if and only if $Z \ge a$ and $\mathcal{A}$ holds.

Or to see it another way, Markov's inequality is valid in any measure space (inspect the proof and note you never use anything about the measure of the entire space).  So this can also be seen as Markov's inequality applied to the function $Z$ on the measure space $\mathcal{A}$.